# IIS 7 - как убрать пробелы в конце строки запроса?

Tags: rewrite, iis-7

Яндекс.Вебмастер показывает много внешних ссылок вида:

```
wwww.domain.ru/folder/%20
```

(вставляют в материал ссылку с пробелом на конце).

Соотв. web-сервер выдает ошибку 404.

Как сделать редирект на тот же URL но без пробела на конце.

Пробовал через IIS Rewrite вот так:

```
    <rule name="No-White-Space-In-End" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)(%20+)$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

И вот так:

```
        <rule name="No-White-Space-In-End" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)(\++)$" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
```

Никак не помогает, все одно выдает (и в логах пишет) 404.

Answer (score 0):

Правило должно быть такое:

```
<rule name="remove space at the end" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)( +)$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

В регулярном выражении надо использовать  вместо `%20`